# iPhone 6s nagged to update to 13.3, so I did but now I cannot use Whatsapp

Tags: ios, upgrade, restore, performance, whatsapp.app

Don't know where to start, did everything wrong. 
My frustation the last 24 hours:
My iPhone 6s request me to update since a couple of months, so yesterday I thought let's do it. In summary:

- did not make a recent backup first
- click update software wireless mode - got a blinking apple logo after 45 mins
- panic mode
- got it connected to iTunes, update went to 75% and then I got a error 9
- tried more times -> error 9
- now it's 03;00
- hit the "set to fabric" + last backup (march 2019) in iTunes
- hopeful, after fabric + backup my phone seemed to work, but then my iPhone freezes - restarts - freezes -restarts after I downloaded apps which only had the icon but need to be downloaded from the cloud
- I read online some apps could be the cause so I deleted a bunch
- (04:30) all apps I do use I reinstalled
- BUT whatsapp is not working along....I removed the app, but in the App Store I only see "open" not a "cloud" or download and on my iPhone I see a general icon with grey lines
- and my iphone freezes - restarts at random times..

What to do, how can I fix this, besides getting a new phone?